# MATLAB GUI - How do I control actions in one window from another window?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a GUI that displays plots, and it launches a "playlist" window.  When I perform an action in the playlist window, is there a way to run a function in the launching window?

To be more clear, if I add files in the playlist window, I would like the first file in the list to be displayed in the launching window, but I would like to do this through a function in the launching window rather than passing the plot handle to the playlist window.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can offer!

Comment: I figured out that I need to get the handle for the launcher.  Every explanation I've found explains how to do this using GUIDE, but I would really like to create this programmatically, and I can't seem to find the command that would get me there.

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest ways to do this, would be using `findobj`.
This looks through graphics objects, finding those that match the provided filter criteria.
As the number of existing figures should be relatively small, it should also be reasonably fast.

Assuming your launcher-figure has some name you can get the launcher figure-handle
e.g. via

```
launcherFig = findobj(0,'type','figure', 'name', <launcher-name>);
```

Or give your lauchner figure a `Tag` that you can search for:

```
% in your launcher-figure code:
launcherFig = figure('Tag', 'MyLauncher');

% and modify the search accordingly:
launcherFig = findobj(0, 'type', 'figure', 'Tag', 'MyLauncher');
```

And, for completeness, though I don't like them, you could use a `global` variable:

```
% in your launcher-figure code:
launcherFig = figure(...);
% store handle in the global variable:
global LauncherHandle;
LauncherHandle = launcherFig;

% no need for a search now anymore, just get the global variable:
global LauncherHandle
```